# Save UITableView data?

Tags: ios, uitableview, save

I am using storyboards and a dynamic UITableView adding my cells like below. I need to know how I can save this text in the UITextField in each cell as well as UISwitch state etc so when I scroll up and down, the data is not lost. Also when the app closes, I need it to show the data entered when reopening. I am pretty new to programming, and this is my first UItableView project. Coding examples would be great, please give as much detail as possible! thank you in advance!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

    // Make cell unselectable and set font.
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:13];

if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    UITextField* tf = nil;
    switch ( indexPath.row ) {
        case 0: {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Name" ;
            tf = nameFieldTextField = [self makeTextField:self.name placeholder:@"John Appleseed"];
            nameFieldTextField.tag = 1;
            [cell addSubview:nameFieldTextField];
            break ;
        }
        case 1: {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Address" ;
            tf = addressFieldTextField = [self makeTextField:self.address placeholder:@"Street Address"];
            addressFieldTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
            [cell addSubview:addressFieldTextField];
            break ;
        }
        case 2: {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Email" ;
            tf = emailFieldTextField = [self makeTextField:self.email placeholder:@"example@gmail.com"];
            emailFieldTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
            [cell addSubview:emailFieldTextField];
            break ;
        }
        case 3: {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Phone" ;
            tf = phoneFieldTextField = [self makeTextField:self.phone placeholder:@"xxx-xxx-xxxx"];
            phoneFieldTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;
            phoneFieldTextField.tag = 10;
            phoneFieldTextField.text = [self formatPhoneNumber:phoneFieldTextField.text deleteLastChar:YES];
            [cell addSubview:phoneFieldTextField];
            break ;
        }
        case 4: {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"DOB" ;
            tf = dateOfBirthTextField = [self makeTextField:self.dateOfBirth placeholder:@"xx/xx/xxxx"];
            dateOfBirthTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
            [cell addSubview:dateOfBirthTextField];
            break ;
        }

    }
    // Textfield dimensions
    tf.frame = CGRectMake(120, 12, 170, 30);

    // Workaround to dismiss keyboard when Done/Return is tapped
    [tf addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldFinished:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

Comment: Take a look at CoreData for saving data persistantly, or if its not that much data you could also use NSUserDefaults. Of course there's also XML etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can make a model object for storing the data.

.h file

```
@interface User : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *phone;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *dob;

- (void)save;
+(User *)savedUser;
```

.m file

```
#define kName    @"Name"
#define kAddress @"Address"
#define kEMail   @"EMail"
#define kPhone   @"Phone"
#define kDOB     @"DOB"

#define kSavedUser @"SavedUser"

@implementation User

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{

    [encoder encodeObject:self.name     forKey:kName];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.address  forKey:kAddress];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.email    forKey:kEMail];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.phone    forKey:kPhone];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.dob      forKey:kDOB];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name       = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kName];
        self.address    = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kAddress];
        self.email      = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kEMail];
        self.phone      = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kPhone];
        self.dob        = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kDOB];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Save

- (void)save{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:kSavedUser];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

+(User *)savedUser{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:kSavedUser];
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
}
```

UITableView DataSource

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.detailTextField.delegate = self;
    [cell.detailTextField setTag:indexPath.row+1];

    switch (indexPath.row+1) {
        case 1:{
            cell.titleLabel.text = @"Name";
            cell.detailTextField.text = self.user.name;
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            cell.titleLabel.text = @"Address";
            cell.detailTextField.text = self.user.address;
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            cell.titleLabel.text = @"EMail";
            cell.detailTextField.text = self.user.email;
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            cell.titleLabel.text = @"Phone";
            cell.detailTextField.text = self.user.phone;
            break;
        }
        case 5:{
            cell.titleLabel.text = @"D.O.B.";
            cell.detailTextField.text = self.user.dob;
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

It's too much to explain. I have attached source code, take a look. 
[Source Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TFTableView.zip)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can I save this data as a pdf easily and send via email from app?

Comment: Also, for multiple sections, how would I do the textFieldDidEndEditing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some sort of persistency. Since you seem to have a very small amount of data, what you need to do is to put your data for your table inside an NSDictionary object by using NSDictionary's writeToFile:atomically: method. You can load the data using NSDictionary's class method dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:, passing as a parameter the place in which you saved your image.

Answer (score 0):

First, for saving data from your app you can use Core Data or NSUserDefaults, NSUserDefaults should be use for saving small amount of data, for the rest use Core Data (there are lots of tutorials regarding core data just google it)

But you have to rewrite your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method because is wrongly implemented.

First use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to check if there are cells already created (maybe you heard about cell reuse, this is how it's done) because right now you are creating a new cell for each call of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called (the method it's called every time a cell shows up on the screen).

Second, after `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` check if the cell that the method returned is nil or not, if it is nil create a new one, if not use the returned cell.

Third, create a custom cell that can have a `UITextField` or a `UISwitch`, and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check the text of your `UITextField`, if is nil the set the placeholder if not leave it as it is this will allow data to be properly displayed when you scroll the table.

Fourth, for `UITextFields` there are delegate methods that are called when user begins/end editing so you don't need to add `[tf addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldFinished:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];`, check UITextFieldDelegate protocol (easy google stuff :))

Fifth (the last one i promise) don't use `=` in on the same line of code, it's ugly and hard to read (`tf = nameFieldTextField = [self makeT...`)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data in sqlite database.Or you can do take one array in view did load.Initially you will insert null value.when your cell will created once you will replace that null object from that uitableviewcell object.And next time when you will load the cell.You can fetch the data directly from that array.

Answer (score 0):

For sample code, take a look at the ["Settings" example project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Settings/Settings/SettingsTableViewController.m) in the [TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools) library on GitHub. It demonstrates how to get user input out of the table. It also shows how you can add dynamic behavior to the table like hiding and showing rows as the inputs change.

It does not show how to persist the values across app sessions. For that look into Core Data or `NSUserDefaults` as @d4Rk suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
    nsmutablearray *arr=[[nsmutablearray alloc] init];
    [arr addobject:[nsnull class]];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];
                cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"cell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
                cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                if (![[saveCellState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
                {
                    cell=(UITableViewCell *)[saveCellState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                }
                if ([[saveCellState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
                {
}
```